# Merge [code-first-migrations] into [ef-migrations]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Despite [code-first-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-first-migrations) is more popular (951 vs. 251) I think it should be merged into having more correct and generic name [ef-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-migrations).

Comment: Maybe as a [synonym-request]?

Comment: @jjj: sounds good to me. But I'd make [ef-migrations] they primary one.

Comment: Already 2 votes for the synonym!  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ef-migrations/synonyms